# What is the time complexity for solving Diophantine equations of degree 2?

Tags: computational-complexity, diophantine-equations

[Manders and Adleman](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000078900442) mention that the computational complexity for binary quadratic Diophantine equations is NP-complete. Has a more specific complexity been claimed for polynomials of the form $Axy + Bx + Cy = D$ where the coefficients are nonnegative integers? The only algorithm I have encountered so far is [Alpern's method](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/METHODS.HTM) for solving $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$, so I use that one and [set $A=0, C=0$](https://forthright48.blogspot.com/2015/07/simple-hyperbolic-diophantine-equation.html). I am looking for the most efficient algorithm (or the lowest complexity claim for such an algorithm) for solving this "simpler" form.

Comment: Your equation has degree 2, not 1. Systems of degree 1 (i.e., linear) Diophantine equations can be solved in polynomial time using the Hermite (or Smith) normal form.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek you are correct, when adding the exponents of x and y in the first term, the degree is 2. Thank you for pointing that out. This pushes me out of the polynomial time class. I have modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

$Axy+Bx+Cy=D$ is $(Ax+C)(Ay+B)=AD+BC$ so it essentially equivalent to factoring $AD+BC$.

Comment: This is the answer I keep coming to as well, but I would like to make sure. For instance, if I set A=1, B=0, D=0, and E=0, then it would take the form of the highly tractable Pell equation ($x^2 - dy^2$=N). But I cancel out the very variables that are needed for that form, and I keep the one's that aren't. And as Emil points out, because I keep the $Bxy$, I am in the quadratic (hyperbolic in this case) form and locked out of the linear form, for which efficient algorithms also exist. So my question reduces to, are any "Pell-like" counterparts available for this form of the binary quadratic?

Comment: The Pell equation $x^2-dy^2=1$ is tractable. I'm not so sure about $x^2-dy^2=N$. And of course if $d=1$, $x^2-y^2=N$, then we're back to factoring. (And even $x^2-dy^2=1$, if $d$ is large, can have an enormous fundamental solution.)

Comment: Thank you Gerry Myerson, yes I forgot the $N=1$, which makes $x=1, y=0$. There are a number of efficient methods to solve for it in that case.

Comment: It's not clear to me that there's an efficient algorithm for solving $x^2-dy^2=1$, if by "efficient" we mean time polynomial in the size of the input, the size of the input being $\log d$. The smallest positive solution can be so big it takes more than polynomial of $\log d$ digits to write it.

Comment: Thank you again for pointing out this detail. The continued fraction approach for $\sqrt{d}$ was the one I came across, where the complexity is within a logarithmic factor of the number of digits in the fundamental solution. So to achieve polynomial time we only require an encoding for the solution that is more compact than base-10 or binary. Nothing so far precludes such symbolic alternatives, AFAIK, although I have not come across any. I would love to investigate techniques of compression, but this formula does not apply to my case.